# johnny sortable: How to use sort.sortable("serialize");

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable

I use:  **http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/**

With this plugin you can change the order of a list or the order of table rows (thats my case). For example with the mouse you drag the fourth row to the second position. Width the plugin method **sort.sortable("serialize")** you have access to the new order.

But how to use **sort.sortable("serialize")** ?

You find an example here: http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#table
I would like to send the new order of my table rows to myurl.php.

How to use **sortable("serialize")** to send the new order via **$.post** to the php script?

HTML:

```
<table class="tablesort">
<tbody>
<tr data-id="39"><td>item 1</td></tr>
<tr data-id="37"><td>item 2</td></tr>
<tr data-id="40"><td>item 3</td></tr>
<tr data-id="61"><td>item 4</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Initialize the plugin
var sort = $(".tablesort").sortable({

  // After changing the order           
  onDrop: function ($item, container, _super) {
    var myObject = sort.sortable("serialize");

    // How to prepare *myObject* for sending?

    $.post('myurl.php', {blah:myObject}, function(){});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To send your new order via $.POST just do:

```
var dataToSend = sort.sortable("serialize").get();
$.post("ajax-sort.php", {test:dataToSend}, function(data){});
```

On ajax-sort.php you recieve something like:

```
[test] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                ([id] => 39)

                            [1] => Array
                                ([id] => 37)

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [subContainer] => false
                                    [id] => 38
                                )

                            ... snip ...
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

If you want to change the structure of this array, override the **serialize()** method in the plugin.

You will find an example of a customized serialize() method here: http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#limited-target

Answer (score 0):

If the table rows are pre-sorted using that plugin, you can iterate over the rows and add their id's to an array.

```
onDrop: function ($item, container, _super) {
    var myObject = sort.sortable("serialize");
    var sorted = [];

    $('tr').each(function () {
        sorted.push($(this).data('id'));
    });

    $.post('myurl.php', {blah: sorted}, function(){});
});
```

I also wrapped `blah` in curly braces to indicate that it is an object. Otherwise you would have gotten a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a script which will sort and convert output into json format :

```
function start_sorting(classvariable){
var output=[];
var parent="";
var selector=$("."+classvariable+" li");
selector.each(function(key,value){
var id=selector.eq(key).attr('id');
var index=key;
        if(selector.eq(key).parent().parent().parent().find(">li").length==0){
        parent='0';
        }else{
        parent=selector.eq(key).parent().parent().parent().find(">li").attr('id');
        }
output.push({id:id,index:index,parent:parent});
});
console.log( JSON.stringify(output));
}
```